# Using ctrl+v to add a screenshot in browser

Tags: javascript, windows, browser, screenshot, paste

I was wondering is it possible to use javascript to adding screenshots to textbox. The program work as follow:

1. We create HTML  where we can write and paste a screenshot.
2. We create javascript function which handle <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and decide if we try to paste a text (then just paste it) or we try to paste a screenshot (then adding the image to  and saving the image on server)

The main problem is: how can I change screenshot to image programicly?
That should work only for windows 7.

Comment: I don't get what you mean with *"how can I change screenshot to image programicly?"*. Is your question about how to capture a screenshot in the browser ?

Comment: You can listen to the [`onpaste`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/paste) event, and get the content from the [`clipboardDate` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent.clipboardData).

Comment: No dystroy. I mean the situation that you already have a screenshot (it's stored in RAM and it's not image yet) and I want to convert this screen to image and add it (for example to browsers DOM and place it somewhere). Passerby thx. I will try your solution.